# new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector()) deprecated

Tags: java, android

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
    }
```

I am new to java and android. Before this i encounter a deprecated by in terms of layout by changing fill parent to match parent. but this one I have no idea after all the searching in the internet. Tq

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue more clearly so that we can solve it

Comment: HI there , found a solution for this . I have to add a context to the constructor.

Comment: gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,new SwipeGestureDetector());

Comment: Gud :) Hope you got your solution solved